# asp.net FormView Data Binding with a Collection of Data

Tags: asp.net, webforms, formview

I have a collection of records, each record has an ID and a description.
Now in my formview I have 8 textboxes and I want each text box to hold description 
of each record.

So if I do this

```
Text='<%# Eval("Record[0].Description") %>' />
```

This gives an error, any other way to do it?

Also can I do it in the markup, or do I need to do it in code behind, under databound method for the formview?

Thanks..

Comment: what error? if you just want to show record repeater is better option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormView is not meant for showing List of Data.

If you have a List of Data, then you should use `GridView` or `ListView`.

Bind your FormView with a datasource having single record and then directly Eval the fields of the datasource.

i.e. do this:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceId">  
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox id="txtDescription" 
                     Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />

        <asp:TextBox id="txtName" 
                     Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />


         ..
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:FormView>
```

so basically, your FormView should contain different DataField and it should be bound to a DataSource having just one Item.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. But here is my situation - I have a formview with edit template and a category in the formview has 8 textboxes. The data of those texboxes is in a collection of 8 records. Now when I go into the edit mode of formview, I get the collection of those 8 records, How do I populate those 8 texboxes with their values, so that a user can make change, and save the data as well??

Comment: your situation is still not clear to me though. See you bind each field of the formView with one record only. if you have placed 8 textboxes inside your formView, you must bind them with 8 different datafields

Comment: yeah, I guess I will break my collection into 8 different data fields, may not be the best way to do it. But it should work.

Comment: you should use ListView. its much simpler. both its edit template and insert template. anyway, you can accept this as an answer if it helped you

Comment: So you mean, using listview within formview and when I save the form, I save the listview as well?

Comment: no i mean, using just the ListView. get rid of this outdated formView. anyway complete your work in hand. take a day off. go and research and develop ListView, you will find it beautiful

Comment: any suggested link to read bout listview. How to perform CRUD operations with listview?

Comment: try [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a repeater inside:

```
<asp:repeater ID="rep" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Record") &>'>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:textbox id="txt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") &>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

In the repeater you will bind to your outer datasource, inside the repeater your datacontext is the record